# Optimize MIN/MAX lookup by constraint on other table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, query-optimization

I have a table `vals` with an integer `id` and some integer `value`. And another table `times` with PRIMARY `id` and an integer `time`.

```
CREATE TABLE times (
  id int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  time int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

CREATE TABLE vals (
  id int(11) NOT NULL,
  value int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY value (value, id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

My goal is to select the highest `value` given a constraint on `time`.

Additionally I know that with a high probability the highest `value` matching the constraint is within the first few highest `value`s, but not necessarily.

Working query:

```
SELECT MAX(value) 
   FROM vals v 
   JOIN times t ON v.id = t.id AND t.time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400
```

However it is not particularly efficient if the tables are big. But whatever way round I change this query, I end up materializing either at least all `id`s satisfying the constraint on `t.time` or all `id`s present in `times` which have a corresponding `id` in `values` [which also is most rows] (or worse), according to `EXPLAIN`.

Getting `SELECT value, id FROM vals ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 10` is very fast thanks to the index.

But I cannot manage to tell mariadb "hey look, please iterate on the by `value` ordered resultset and give me the first value matching this condition by its id".

Doing something akin to:

```
SELECT value 
FROM (
    SELECT value, 
          (SELECT time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400 
              FROM times t WHERE t.id = v.id) AS active
    FROM vals v
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 10
) x 
WHERE active LIMIT 1
```

is pretty fast (and I'd then increase the `LIMIT 10` to `LIMIT 100` to `LIMIT 1000` etc. in code to successively search a larger amount of rows if none is found) as this actually just fetches the `time` for the N highest values.

However, is there a way to do that in a single query, without materializing the full resultset on the `times` table?

P.s.: Changing the columns is not acceptable, altering indices is.

The database version used is mariadb 10.5. To clarify on the actual contents:

- Most (80%-90%) `time`s in the `times` table are greater than `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400`. The `id`s are auto_increment with a lot of holes.
- `vals` contains hundreds of different `value`s overall, most (60%) entries in `times` have a corresponding entry in `vals`.
- Both tables have a couple millions of rows.

Comment: [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: @Stu Edited :-P (In the end, the codebase this is from is very old and using these old style joins all over the place and I continue doing so for consistency. But le'ts focus on the question itself.)

Comment: The range of the [`TIME` data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time.html) is ('-838:59:59' to '838:59:59') (±34.9 days), and it's generally used to store times of day, not complete timestamps.  So `time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400` makes no sense. Can you [edit] your question to clarify your application?

Comment: Try using [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-explain.html).  Prefix your query with the word `EXPLAIN` and show us the results. Or better yet try `ANALYZE` (`EXPLAIN ANALYZE` in some versions). It runs the query and shows how MySQL satisfied it.

Comment: @O.Jones It's defined as an int, not a time data type

Answer (score 0):

I would never try to create tables that have columns as reserved words that may cause confusion.  Although Time itself may not be, consider better naming.  However, that said, I would first start by having compound indexes as below:

```
Table    Index
Times    ( time, id)  -- to optimize your time filtering requirement
Vals     ( id, value ) -- since the ID will be the basis of the JOIN, not the value
```

Now, your query.  To get the filtered set of records, do a query of your times table base just on that basis and you get the IDs.  That is then joined to the values table

```
SELECT 
      MAX( v.value) 
   FROM 
      times t
         JOIN vals v
            on t.id = v.id
   where
      t.time > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 86400
```

Your where is optimized by the times index on the time column, that is all that needs.  Then, a direct JOIN to the values that qualify the times based on the common ID between them.  Finally, its just the MAX() value from the values table.  Since no aggregation, it will just return a single record out of all that qualify from the time restriction.

Comment: The problem is, as noted in the question, that most rows *are* matching the filter (of t.time) (I'm talking like 80% of the rows). Your query is btw returning the same query plan than mine, having your indices. The query plan according to explain is: times table has type `range`, returning 480k rows with extras "Using where, using index" and then using `ref` for vals. (if vals has a primary key it will use that and then `eq_ref`)

Comment: So, essentially, it's a tiny bit faster because it can use only the index, with your proposed indices, but sadly, mariadb seems to still do the full search (the query with the indices as you propose takes 0.7 seconds on the staging environment with a fraction of the data) :-/

Comment: @bwoebi, without better context of what possible "values" are, why not put some limiting range you would expect for a given time period?  We have no other context to what the times or values are for.

Comment: I can't really disclose the context (the tables are obviously simplified), but in general, it's mostly future dates. I've added a couple more points to the end of the question, does that make it more explicit?

Comment: @bwoebi, based on the volume of data, you might want to consider a pre-aggregate summary table (sometimes common with relatively static data) that may have on each given day things like count(), min(), max() values.  So then you could find which day quickly that had a highest date and be done with it. (or lowest, or whatever else that MAY help optimization, especially if historical data is static and not changing.  If it does change, having triggers in place that can re-calculate for a given day changes ARE made.